# Files deleted inside docker container not freeing space

Tags: docker, amazon-ecs

I have a container running and by default it uses 10 GB of space. Last night the container space was filled by the log files generated by the system. Since log file grew to 8 GB, I emptied the log file but still my container is 100% disk full. It never released the 8GB space cleared from the log file. Any idea?

---

```
root@c7:/app# df -h .
 Filesystem                            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/docker-202:1-264176-9aff6   10G   10G   20K 100% /


root@c7:/app# df -i
Filesystem                             Inodes IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/docker-202:1-264176-9aff6   68368 67605     763   99% /
```

Thanks,
Manish Joshi

Comment: Maybe try to restart your docker service after deleting the log file. Not sure but difficult to debug. You need to perform `du -sh` and search for the path which still contains so much data.

Comment: I ended up restarting my container to fix this. There was not the kind of data the container was claiming. It could be a one-off issue, but if it occurs again, I'll probably raise a bug.

Comment: are you running just a single container? how many times have you redeployed? what is the output you get when you run `docker images`? It could be possible that your images are taking up the space.

Answer (score 0):

May be, you can try running this command on host

```
fstrim /proc/$(docker inspect --format='{{ .State.Pid }}' <cid>)/root
```